# How to Hide/remove maximise button from AVPlayer/AVPlayer view controller

Tags: avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayeritem

When we implemented avplayer and we dont need one of the avplayer controller i.e maximise button, So unable to hide that button.

I tried to hide maximise button using hide all controlls but individually not possible to hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can hide the maximize button from getting subviews from AVPlayerViewController.
In Subviews need to find the **AVMobileChromelessDisplayModeControlsView**
class object and hide that view.

```
if let orientaion = playerVC.view.subviews.first?.subviews.last?.subviews.first    {
        orientaion.isHidden = true
    }
```